# cygwin g++ can't find pmr namespace and related issues

Tags: c++, c++17, cygwin, header-files, c++pmr

Ok so I decided to compile some code from godbolt locally on my Windows 10 64bit using Cygwin and the cygwin terminal. It compiles fine on godbolt, but cygwin/mingw64 g++ spits out loads of errors along the lines of:

```
jsontest.cpp:310:23: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std::pmr’; did you mean ‘std::string’?
  310 | auto expand(std::pmr::string s, ospolicy policy) {
      |                       ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/string:39,
                 from jsontest.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/stringfwd.h:79:33: note: ‘std::string’ declared here
   79 |   typedef basic_string<char>    string;
                  ^~~~~~
```

There are a lot more issues but I think they are all related to this one. When I looked into the headerfile for `#include<string>` (which I did), std::pmr::string is defenitely defined there. The file stringfwd.h just forward declares basic_string templates so it should still find the definitions.

This is the section inside the string headerfile:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L && _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
  namespace pmr {
    template<typename _Tp> class polymorphic_allocator;
    template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>>
      using basic_string = std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
                         polymorphic_allocator<_CharT>>;
    using string    = basic_string<char>;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_CHAR8_T
    using u8string  = basic_string<char8_t>;
#endif
    using u16string = basic_string<char16_t>;
    using u32string = basic_string<char32_t>;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
    using wstring   = basic_string<wchar_t>;
#endif
  } // namespace pmr
//...
} // namespace std
```

You can see that the std::pmr::string typedef is guarded and only availabe when the C++ version is greater than 17 (as polymorphic memory resources are only available from C++17) and something about the CXX ABI.

I'm using gcc 11.3 which should be able to support even C++20 language features. I'm not getting it... what am I doing differently than godbolt?

**EDIT:**

Try this to reproduce:

1. Download cygwin from [here](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) and install it the usual way (add g++ to environment vars)
2. Create testfolder with the following file:

**test_pmr.cpp** ([CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory_resource%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::pmr::string+str+%3D+%22Hello+World!!%22%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+str+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.66057441253264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.33942558746736,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>

int main()
{
    std::pmr::string str = "Hello World!";

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

3. Compile using the following command:

   g++ -std=c++20 test_pmr.cpp -s -o test_pmr

When I follow this I get this error:

```
test_pmr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_pmr.cpp:6:15: error: ‘string’ is not a member of ‘std::pmr’; did you mean ‘std::string’?
    6 |     std::pmr::string str = "Hello World!";
      |               ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iosfwd:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from test_pmr.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/stringfwd.h:79:33: note: ‘std::string’ declared here
   79 |   typedef basic_string<char>    string;
      |                                 ^~~~~~
test_pmr.cpp:8:18: error: ‘str’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘std’?
    8 |     std::cout << str << std::endl;
      |                  ^~~
      |                  std
```

**EDIT2:**

It works using only [MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/) with static linking:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ test_pmr.cpp -s -o test_pmr
```

So the problem seems to lie in an incorrect stdlib configuration that ships with cygwin.

Comment: what is your `g++` command line? Copy+paste it from the console output.

Comment: @DougHenderson `g++ jsontest jsontest.cpp -o -s -I ../../include -std=c++20`

Comment: Given a choice, I would use this `g++ -std=c++20 -I ../../include jsontest.cpp -s -o jsontest`, so general options, input options, input, output options, output. In my own code I always add more options: `-Wall -Wextra` and sometimes `-Werror`.

Comment: @DougHenderson Thanks but that doesn't make a difference. The problem is in compiling. I will add an example for reproduction to original post ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use anything in the `std::pmr` namespace, it looks like you need to add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to your general compiler flags. I got a clean and successful compile and execute with `g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI test_pmr.cpp -s -o test_pmr.exe`

Comment: Thank you, interesting. Any clue on why the flag is not set by default?

Comment: No. I have never needed to use it. When I used the right option, I could see that the section from the string header that you quoted in the initial question was not getting included in the pre-processed source (the .i file).